Linking - How to trigger a phone call when clicking a button through a browser on a mobile phone?
The react code works fine when running through an app, however, when running through a browser, it just opens a blank tab on iOS, on android it opens a tab where the url is the phone number.
Am I missing a critical piece of understanding of how React Native Web is used to build websites? How can I use react native to build a website where a button presents the device's modal to call a phone number?
EDIT:: On Safari for ios, it opens another tab and then presents the user with the modal(this is good enough). On iOS, on Google Chrome, it opens and closes a tab and nothing happens. On Android, it opens a tab and nothing happens. Why the variation?
const callNumber = phone => {
  // console.log('callNumber ----> ', phone);
  let phoneNumber = phone;
  if (Platform.OS !== 'android') {
    phoneNumber = `telprompt:${phone}`;
  }
  else  {
    phoneNumber = `tel:${phone}`;
  }
  Linking.canOpenURL(phoneNumber)
    .then(supported => {
      if (!supported) {
        Alert.alert('Phone number is not available');
      } else {
        return Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};



I think you should segregate the platforms and then act on each platform like it needs. On the web, you should do the following:
const callNumber = (phone) => {
  let phoneNumber = phone;
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') { // <== Fix this condition
    phoneNumber = `telprompt:${phone}`;
  }
  else  {
    phoneNumber = `tel:${phone}`;
  }
  
  if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
    window.open(phoneNumber); // <== Pay attention here
  } else {
    Linking.canOpenURL(phoneNumber)
      .then(supported => {
        if (!supported) {
          Alert.alert('Phone number is not available');
        } else {
          return Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
};




    import { Platform, Linking, Alert } from 'react-native';

const callNumber = phone => {
  let phoneNumber = phone;
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    phoneNumber = `telprompt:${phone}`;
  } else {
    phoneNumber = `tel:${phone}`;
  }

  Linking.canOpenURL(phoneNumber)
    .then(supported => {
      if (!supported) {
        Alert.alert('Phone number is not available');
      } else {
        return Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error opening phone app:', error));
};

export default callNumber;




Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide an additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly edit your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
